# How Can I Get A Dictionary Value From Python?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-views, django-templates

I was trying to convert a look up today to a data dictionary...for performance reasons...

It's almost working...Except that it's duplicating the entries on my output...

Here is my code in question...

```
class Calendar(HTMLCalendar):
    def __init__(self, year=None, month=None, user=None):
        self.user = user
        self.year = year
        self.month = month
        super(Calendar, self).__init__()

    # formats a day as a td
    # filter events by day
    def formatday(self, day, requests):
        requests_per_day = DailyPlannerRequest.objects.filter(Q(created_by=self.user)).distinct().order_by('start_time')

        daily_planner_events1 = []

        for requests in requests_per_day:
            requests_per_day_dict = model_to_dict(requests)
            daily_planner_events1.append(requests_per_day_dict)

        daily_planner_events1 = dict()

        events = add_event_dates(requests_per_day)

        all_event_dates = []

        for event in events:
            for date in event.dates:
                if date not in all_event_dates and date.month == self.month and date.year == self.year:
                    all_event_dates.append(date)

        for event in events:
            for date in event.dates:
                if date in all_event_dates and date not in daily_planner_events1 and date.month == self.month and date.year == self.year:
                    daily_planner_events1[date] = [event]
                else:
                    if date.month == self.month and date.year == self.year:
                        daily_planner_events1[date].append(event)
                        # daily_planner_events[date].append(events)

        d = ''

        for requests in requests_per_day:
            for event in daily_planner_events1:
                if event.day == day:
                    d += f'<li> {requests.get_html_url} </li>'

        if day != 0:
            return f"<td><span class='date'>{day}</span><ul> {d} </ul></td>"
        return '<td></td>'
```

The code above works...Except it's giving me incorrect output...The problem piece in particular is this...

```
for requests in requests_per_day:
    for event in daily_planner_events1:
        if event.day == day:
            d += f'<li> {requests.get_html_url} </li>'
```

It's not narrowing down the output specific enough.

I've played with this all afternoon..and the other version that actually kinda works is...

```
    for event in daily_planner_events1:
        if event.day == day:
            d += f'<li> {event.get_html_url} </li>'
```

If I remove the request piece and change request to event it works exactly how I want except the get_html_url piece now doesn't work.  It won't access the ID from the dictionary and as far as I can tell the way that I'm comparing the events...it doesn't have the ID information to provide.  What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for any thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is very convoluted and could probably be made a whole lot simpler. For example, `daily_planner_events1` is used as a list and then replaced with a `dict()` before you do anything with it? It's very hard to review your question because your code isn't straightforward and some of the functions aren't included, like `add_event_dates` and `get_html_url`.

To try and answer your question, the most likely reason why you are struggling to get your intended results is because your final nested for-loop aren't connected to each other properly, i.e. they aren't looping on related objects. Hence removing the outer for-loop has helped, presumably the reason why you aren't getting the output you want is because `event.get_html_url` isn't returning the right thing.

I went through all your code to try and figure out what's happening and think it could be far more succinct. As I mentioned already, I don't know what some of the functions do and I suspect there is a different model somewhere, so some things might need to change:

```py
def formatday(self, day, requests):
    # if the day is zero then return an empty table cell, don't run through any more code
    if day == 0:
        return '<td></td>'

    # Q expression isn't needed here
    requests_per_day = DailyPlannerRequest.objects.filter(created_by=self.user)...

    # repeated checks of self.month and self.year can be done in an ORM filter
    all_event_dates = SomeEventModel.filter(
        dates__month=self.month, 
        dates__year=self.year
    )

    # no idea what this does?
    events = add_event_dates(requests_per_day)

    d = ''
    # remove the if-statement and use another filter
    for event in all_event_dates.filter(day=day):
        d += f'<li> {event.get_html_url} </li>'

    # return your table cell with the list appended
    return f"<td><span class='date'>{day}</span><ul> {d} </ul></td>"
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the response.  Long story short, I do have an ORM type approach already that already works...it's just that I thought that maybe using a DataDictionary approach would be more performant?  You are correct that I  haven't linked the loops properly.  The challenge I face currently is trying to get a data dictionary attribute to compare to a filter attribute.

Answer (score 0):

After a week of trial and error...it turns out I needed to add a .date() to the loop to make it work.

```
for event in requests_per_day:
    for request in daily_planner_events1:
        if request.day == day and request == event.start_time.date():
            d += f'<li> {event.get_html_url} </li>'
```